# MicrosoftAjaxMinifier doesn't seem to remove "unreachable code"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, minify, microsoft-ajax-minifier, bundletransformer

I'm using this with `BundleTransformer` from nuget and `System.Web.Optimisation` in an ASP.Net app. According to various docs this [minifier](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584) is supposed to "remove unreachable code". I know it's not as aggressive as google closure (which I can't use presently) but I can't get even the simplest cases to work, eg;

```
function foo() {
}
```

where `foo` isn't called from anywhere. I can appreciate the argument that says this might be an exported function but I can't see a way to differentiate that. All my JS code is concatenated so it would be able to say for sure whether that function was needed or not if I can find the right switches.

The only way I've found to omit unnecessary code is to use the `debugLookupList` property in the web.config for `BundleTransformer` but that seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut. It's not very granular.

Does anyone have an example of how to write so-called 'unreachable code' that this minifier *will* recognise?

Here's a place to [test online](http://sundgaard.dk/javascript-minify.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the *minifier* has any way of knowing if a globally defined function can be removed safely (as it doesn't know the full scope).  On the other hand it might not remove any unused functions and might only be interested in unreachable code (i.e. code after a `return`).

Using the JavaScript Module Pattern, your unused private functions would most likely get hoovered up correctly (although I've not tested this).  In the example below, the *minifier* should only be confident about removing the function called `privateFunction`. Whether it considers unused functions as unreachable code is another matter.

```
var AmazingModule = (function() {
    var module = {};

    function privateFunction() {
        // ..
    }

    module.otherFunction = function() {
        // ..
    };

    return module;
}());

function anotherFunction() {
    // ..
}
```

Comment: That's a fair point, your example above skips privateFunction. I guess I'm hoping for too much that it will chase down call graphs. My code is generated from TypeScript so uses the module pattern all-over. On the basis of your example above (I've added a test url to my question) wherever I've used the exports keyword I can't expect it to remove those function. I was hoping it would look to see if those exports had been called by anyone, but I think it works more like your example. Once the function is in global scope it can't be cleaned up.